# With Backbone - how to access models in collection from JSON

Tags: json, backbone.js, collections

I'm new to backbone and can't seem to find any similar threads to help me solve this.

My problem is simple - I want to grab a JSON file for a collection, and then access those models from my view. I seem to be able to get the JSON data, but I have no idea how to now access those models in the collection from my view.

I've played with using fetch in a view triggered by a click event (see bottom) but it doesn't seem the way I should be using it, since I need to hit fetch every time and then am not using underscores methods to manipulate the models.

I'm using coffeescript so I apologize if people want to see this in plain js

Thanks for any direction.

Example JSON:

```
 [
    {
        "name": "mouse",
        "level": "1"
    },

    {
        "name": "bird",
        "level": "1"
    },

    {
        "name": "unicorn",
        "level": "2"
    },
    {
        "name": "narwhal",
        "level": "2"
    }    
]
```

MODEL:

```
class MagnetModel extends Backbone.Model

magnet_model = new MagnetModel
```

COLLECTION:

```
class MagnetCollection extends Backbone.Collection

    model: MagnetModel
    url: "js/json/dolch.json"


magnet_collection = new MagnetCollection
magnet_collection.fetch
    success: (response) ->
        log response.toJSON() # I can see the data here - but now what? Where does it "live" or where do I tell it to live?
```

"WORKING" VIEW: 
I can get the data to show in a view like this, but don't think I should be doing it this way since I need to "fetch" every time :

```
loadLevel: (level) ->
    level = $(level.currentTarget).attr('id')


        words = magnet_collection.fetch
            success: (response) ->
                log 'good fetch'
                data = response.toJSON()

                console.log( data[0][level] )
            error: ->
                log 'bad fetch'
```

Comment: I would read up on the basics of collections, I found http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#collections to be a good source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access models without `toJSON()` call.

This will get first model from collection:

```
var model = response.at(0);
```

You can also search by collection:

```
var model = response.findWhere({ name: "mouse" });
```

It's better to have `id` instead of the `name` and use it with method `get`

```
var model = response.get("id");
```

To get the level you need also use `get` method on the model

```
var level = model.get("level");
```